# Test execution showing the error 'Cannot read property next of null'

Tags: javascript

I've created a method to remove an element from the linked list at a specific index that I'm passing as an argument to the function call using JavaScript. The code that I have written for the function so far is:

```
this.removeAt = function(count){
    var currentNode = head;
    var previousNode;
    if(count==0 || count>=this.length || count<0){
        return null;
    } else {
        while(count) {
             count--;
            previousNode = currentNode;
            currentNode = currentNode.next;        
        }
        previousNode.next = currentNode.next; 
    }
    length --; 
    return currentNode.element;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell because there are external variables that aren't present. If you could provide a snippet including at least partial markup that would help.

Comment: step through in the debugger of any browser you use and see what's happening, your loop could be running one too many times

Comment: pls visit the link given down below/;

https://learn.freecodecamp.org/coding-interview-prep/data-structures/remove-elements-from-a-linked-list-by-index

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  All of the necessary code and error messages should be included in the question, not in external links.  External links, change and disappear, making the question not useful later on.